# Shutting down a windows process from Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

One can see there are list of process running in a Windows operating system just by opening the task manager. Now my question is if it is possible to shut down one such process from Mathematica front end.

[image]

I mean we need to write a script say to kill the "Process Tree" if the process is taking more than 95 percent of system RAM or it takes more than X minutes or seconds to complete. I dont know if that can be done from MMA but if possible it will come really handy in my project.

BR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used a method to shut down a process in my reply here:

[How can I make Mathematica kernel pause for an external file creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665493/how-can-i-make-mathematica-kernel-pause-for-an-external-file-creation/7665825#7665825)

```
taskkill /f /fi "imagename eq apame_win64.exe"
```

E.g. shutting down notepad:

```
ReadList["!taskkill /F /FI \"IMAGENAME eq notepad.exe\"", String]
```

This can be used in conjunction with tasklist to identify memory use:

```
ReadList["!tasklist", String]
```

Answer (score 2):

You will probably want to use the `Run` function, and the `TSKILL` shell command.

```
TSKILL processid | processname [/SERVER:servername] [/ID:sessionid | /A] [/V]

  processid           Process ID for the process to be terminated.
  processname         Process name to be terminated.
  /SERVER:servername  Server containing processID (default is current).
                         /ID or /A must be specified when using processname
                         and /SERVER
  /ID:sessionid       End process running under the specified session.
  /A                  End process running under ALL sessions.
  /V                  Display information about actions being performed.
```

Comment: Can you give me a simple example?

Comment: @Plato, sorry, I thought that part was evident.  If `notepad.exe` is running, simply `Run["TSKILL Notepad"]`.